# Use Google Search to Filter Data on Server for Users

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-appliance

I would like to use Google Search capability to search data on a server (whatever format, I can parse the data into that format). But am a bit confused by all the options/deprecated services.

So, lets say I have a couple thousand text documents. I would like to be able to search them and bring up the most relevant parts of the document with its file name. I could put it in a NoSQL database or whatever. I would prefer to keep the content "private" but could set up a static site. I don't want a Google Search Appliance.

We license this data out to other institutions and have web apps, iOS and Android apps also.

I just need a good way to search them since they are multiple languages.

I figured Google would be a good route to go since I could type in `Knocked Up` and have it return a file with `Pregnancy`.

Are there alternatives to Google that would work just as well?

Answer (score 2):

GSA has been discontinued but this news article recommends many alternative solutions similar to that software http://fortune.com/2016/05/27/google-search-appliance-gone/